# What is the official Rust guidance for interoperability with C++, in particular passing and returning structs as arguments?

Tags: c++, c, rust

I'm trying to adapt some layers of existing C++ code to be used by Rust and apparently the way is through a C API.

For example, one function might return a struct as an object

```cpp
#pragma pack(push,4)
struct Result {
    char ch;
    int32_t sum1;
    int32_t sum2;
};
#pragma pack(pop)

extern "C"
Result
muladd(int32_t a, int32_t b, int32_t c) {
    return Result{1, a+b*c, a*b+c};
}
```

And from Rust I'm doing

```rust
#[repr(C,align(4))]
pub struct Result {
    pub ch: i8,
    pub sum1: i32,
    pub sum2: i32,
}

extern "C" {
    pub fn muladd( a:i32, b:i32, c:i32 ) -> Result;
}

pub fn usemuladd( val: i32 ) -> i32 {
    unsafe {
       let res = muladd( val, val, val );
       return res.sum1;
    }
}
```

I'm seeing odd results with respect to alignment and packing of structures. I have read that Rust can play around with structs, and neither ordering or packing are guaranteed.

It seems that using `#[repr(C)]` and `extern "C"` is the key to a happy compatibility layer. My question is then: can I trust that these two will get me solid through or there will always be unannounced edge cases that I have to worry about?

https://godbolt.org/z/aEh4jKxxf

Comment: I suggest changing the title of this question, as “is there a guide to…” is likely to get the question closed (asking for references to external resources is considered off topic on stackoverflow)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner But if I ask "Is this good practice.." that would be opinion-based right?

Comment: Yes, stackoverflow is a maze full of traps for questioners.  :)  Still, it is possible to ask a question that doesn't hit any of the tripwires.

Comment: Side note: C integer types should be represented as e.g. [`c_char`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/os/raw/type.c_char.html), and [`c_int`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/os/raw/type.c_int.html) in Rust, rather than `i8` and `i32`, since the C types are platform-dependant.

Comment: @Jmb Could you use `iN`/`uN` with `intN_t`/`uintN_t`? The issue is that I couldn't find any guarantees about alignment in C++... Rust doesn't either though, so maybe they match? https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-layout.html#primitive-data-layout

Comment: @Jmb I never use `int` and `long` types as a matter of safety. Char, yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`extern "C"` on both sides + `#[repr(C)]` on the Rust side + only using C-compatible types for interfacing between C++ and Rust, should work.

Alternatively, see [`cxx`](https://cxx.rs/) and [`autocxx`](https://docs.rs/autocxx/latest/autocxx/).

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to get a translation between the codes, you could use [cbindgen](https://github.com/eqrion/cbindgen) and specify the output as C++ which is already default, or you could follow Solomon Ucko's suggestion.